# Select com MYSQL quando existe em uma tabela e na outra não

Tags: mysql, select

Tenho dua tabelas:

QUIZ

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

QUIZ_GERAL

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu precisaria listar dados das duas tabelas quando:

- O ID do usuário logado for igual ao campo IDCONTA

**OU**

- Quando existe uma linha na tabela QUIZ e não existe uma linha na tabela QUIZ_GERAL com o IDQUIZ e o IDLOGADO do usuário logado

Até agora fiz algo assim:

```
$sql1 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM quiz_geral 
RIGHT JOIN quiz ON quiz_geral.idquiz = quiz.id
WHERE (quiz_geral.idconta = :idLogado) OR (quiz_geral.id IS NULL)
ORDER BY quiz.ano ASC, quiz.mes ASC');
```

O problema é que para o usuário com **idconta** 1 não lista o quiz com **id** 1, pois o SELECT entende que já existe ele, mas existe ele para o **idconta** 2.

Como fazer para listar todos os quizes (1,2,3) para cada usuário.

(simplifiquei bem as tabelas e selects, elas são mais complexas, mas a minha dúvida está nessa etapa que falei)

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma simples, aproveitando a query que você mesmo já montou, é trocar o INNER JOIN por RIGHT JOIN. O problema da sua query é que o INNER JOIN remove do resultado os valores que não passarem na condição informada no JOIN:

```
quiz_geral.idquiz = quiz.id
```

Com o RIGHT JOIN, o MySQL preenche os valores não encontrados na tabela quiz_geral com NULL como a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aí é só incluir o teste de id nulo na query:

```
SELECT * FROM quiz_geral 
RIGHT JOIN quiz ON quiz_geral.idquiz = quiz.id
WHERE (quiz_geral.idconta = 1 AND quiz_geral.respondido <> quiz_geral.total) OR (quiz_geral.id IS NULL)
ORDER BY quiz.ano ASC, quiz.mes ASC
```

Melhor ainda seria trocar o RIGHT JOIN, pelo LEFT join, como mencionado na documentação do MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html):

> RIGHT JOIN works analogously to LEFT JOIN. To keep code portable across databases, it is recommended that you use LEFT JOIN instead of RIGHT JOIN.

E você teria algo como:

```
SELECT * FROM quiz 
LEFT JOIN quiz_geral ON quiz_geral.idquiz = quiz.id
WHERE (quiz_geral.idconta = 1 AND quiz_geral.respondido <> quiz_geral.total) OR (quiz_geral.id IS NULL)
ORDER BY quiz.ano ASC, quiz.mes ASC
```

Só um adendo, é interesante utilizar os nomes dos campos ao invés de * no SELECT já que você tem 2 tabelas com o mesmo nome de campo (id) e isso pode gerar conflitos no resultado.

Comment: Muito obrigado, é isso aí! Sobre o * no SELECT, deixei aqui assim apenas pra não atrapalhar, o SELECT será bem maior, mais deixei só a parte que tinha dúvidas!

Comment: Quando sai dos testes e fui para a prática, deu erro. Se adiciono no QUIZ_GERAL uma linha para outro usuário (idconta), o NULL não funciona caso existe essa linha para um dos usuários...

Comment: Editei a pergunta para entender melhor